# Shell script for going through files and deleting or compressing them

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

> List, one at a time, all files larger than 100K in the /home/username directory tree. Give the user the option to delete or compress the file, then proceed to show the next one. Write to a logfile the names of all deleted files and the deletion times.

Could anyone help me solve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It seems you're asking us to do all the hard work for you which means you'll learn nothing...

Comment: Plus: your script would be very inefficient. What happens if a user has hundreds of files... are they expected to go through every file?

Comment: The problem is that i don't know how to show the files to the user at a time so that he decides to compress it or delete it. All i got is this.                   find -type f -size +100k                                                                                   Oh, and it's a homework, the professor gave us this instructions, but i really don't know how to do it :S

Comment: We're not going to do your homework for you. You need to spend more time listening, researching and trying things yourself. We're not that sort of site. Hint: the `find` is a good start but you've been given a set of directories to search in... Wouldn't it be a good start to obtain the user's home directory you want to scan?

Comment: Well, thanks anyway, the thing is that i've been reading and searching  everywhere, i just like some advice on how to do it, not to solve it for me. In the title i wrote "help me solve it" not solve it for me

Comment: You did ask, yes, but you showed no evidence of what you'd tried so far, what you thought may work etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some (rather inefficient) pseudocode to get you started:

```
for filename in (recurse through all files)
  skip if size(filename) < 100K
  display filename
  response =  ask user what they want to do
  if response == "delete"
    delete filename
    write filename + current time to logfile
  else if response == "compress"
    compress filename
```

It's inefficient because it'll go through every file even if it's smaller than 100K. Optimizing it by using `find` instead of a `for` loop would be an exercise for you.

Now, with Bash you can easily recurse through files by setting `shopt -s globstar` and `shopt -s nullglob`, then using `**/*`:

```
for file in /home/username/**/*; do
  echo "$file"
done
```

The rest is really simple [Bash scripting](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/). By doing a web search for command examples ("get input from user", "write to a file", "compress file") you'll find plenty of resources on the Internet.